# Table border is not visible

Tags: css, xml, blogger

I want give border via inbuild CSS in XML for a blog. See the sample: [iPhone 12 mini](https://mobixlite.blogspot.com/2021/04/apple-iphone-12-mini.html). I have add the following code:

```
.table{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

But, it does not give a border. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have assigned the right class to the element you want to style. On the  sample page there are no elements with the `.table` class.

If you can only access CSS and you want to style elements on the page over which you don't have direct control, you can try to select elements by their name, their classes, IDs and other attributes using [*CSS selectors*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors#reference_table_of_selectors). You can use both single selectors and combination of them to obtain the specificity you need. There is also `!important` CSS property which you can better not use to avoid maintenance difficulties of the code.

Answer (score 1):

In your sample there are 2 things that can cause your problem:

1. there is a RESET CSS that include table with `border: 0;`

and

2. in your css code you tried, you used `.table` - this means that your table has a `class="table"`, and from what I saw in the sample, that is not the case.

My sugestion is either to add the `class="table"` to your table and try again your css...

Something like so:

```
.table{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

<body>
  <table class="table" border="1">
    ...
  </table>
</body>
```

Or remove the dot (and the need to include a class) - and use in your css simply :

```
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Mind you that this code, as per your sample css, only put a border around the table and not on all inner elements of said table.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have made RESET CSS > border: 1; It's works now.